# Dataframe non-null values differ from value_counts() values

Tags: pandas

There is an inconsistency with dataframes that I cant explain. In the following, I'm not looking for a workaround (already found one) but an explanation of what is going on under the hood and how it explains the output.

One of my colleagues which I talked into using python and pandas, has a dataframe "data" with 12,000 rows.
"data" has a column "length" that contains numbers from 0 to 20. she wants to divided the dateframe into groups by length range: 0 to 9 in group 1, 9 to 14 in group 2, 15 and more in group 3. her solution was to add another column, "group", and fill it with the appropriate values. she wrote the following code:

```
data['group'] = np.nan
mask = data['length'] < 10;
data['group'][mask] = 1;
mask2 = (data['length'] > 9) & (data['phraseLength'] < 15);
data['group'][mask2] = 2;
mask3 = data['length'] > 14;
data['group'][mask3] = 3;
```

This code is not good, of course. the reason it is not good is because you dont know in run time whether `data['group'][mask3]`, for example, will be a view and thus actually change the dataframe, or it will be a copy and thus the dataframe would remain unchanged. It took me quit sometime to explain it to her, since she argued correctly that she is doing an assignment, not a selection, so the operation should always return a view.

But that was not the strange part. the part the even I couldn't understand is this:
After performing this set of operation, we verified that the assignment took place in two different ways:

1. By typing `data` in the console and examining the dataframe summary. It told us we had a few thousand of null values. The number of null values was the same as the size of `mask3` so we assumed the last assignment was made on a copy and not on a view.
2. By typing `data.group.value_counts()`. That returned 3 values: 1,2 and 3 (surprise) we then typed `data.group.value_counts.sum()` and it summed up to 12,000!

So by method 2, the group column contained no null values and all the values we wanted it to have. But by method 1 - it didnt!

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

You dont' want to set values this way for exactly the reason you pointed; since you don't know if its a view, you don't know that you are actually changing the data. 0.13 will raise/warn that you are attempting to do this, but easiest/best to just access like:

```
data.loc[mask3,'group'] = 3
```

which will guarantee you inplace setitem

Comment: Yes, but this is not what I have asked. I said in the post that i know the right to do so (same as what you suggested) what Im asking (and not understanding) is the strange behavior explained at the end of the post. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: might be related to a bug in 0.12. try 0.13rc1 and see if repeats. Their was a very subtle cache updating bug (which is what you get when you access a dataframe like ``df.column_name`` yields a Series). This is a cached series.